# Typst reference elements from another file

Tags: typst

I am writing a document that have each chapter as a separate file. The structure is like

```
main.typ  
ch_1.typ  
|-- fig_1  
ch_2.typ
```

Within `ch_1.typ` I have a figure with a label, say `<fig_1>`. In `ch_2.typ` I would like to reference it using `@fig_1`. However, when compiling `ch_2.typ`, the compiler raises the error **label does not exists in the document**.

The reference works when I compile `main.typ`, even though there are some warnings. However, I still cannot compile `ch_2.typ` on its own, which defeats the meaning of a separate file structure.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typst supports cross-referencing another file, as long as they are both included by a common ancestor. [This project](https://typst.app/project/r8HWYahuUBENyAdgrr2aNC) demonstrates this with the setup from your question.

The problem could be in your local setup. For example, the Visual Studio Code extension "Typst LSP" is known to treat every file independently, producing these sorts of errors.

You can try to compile the project by running `typst compile main.typ` in your terminal instead, which should work. You will need to obtain a Typst compiler from a package manager or GitHub if you do not yet have a standalone installation for your shell. If you want Typst to keep running and recompile when files change, use `typst watch main.typ` instead.

Comment: Thank you. I am indeed using the LSP for compilation, and have not tried using `watch`. My experience with `watch` was not great though, that's why I mainly use the LSP. But I will definitely check that out, knowing that it would work that way.